# Nested event listeners in Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, addeventlistener

I am doing a Chrome app, and I have an event listener that first listens to see if all the DOM is ready, and after that it triggers two more listeners regarding click buttons. I nested all of them this way:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var cf = document.getElementById('conv');
    var gf = document.getElementById('gotof');

    cf.addEventListener('click', convert, false);
    gf.addEventListener('click', gotof, false);

},false);
```

But in the console I still get the message of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null
```

Which happens because I am trying to call the id `conv` when it still didn't have time to load in the DOM, but... didn't my first event listener took care of that?? I guessed that whatever you punt inside the function of the event with DOMContentLoaded, wouldn't run unless everything was loaded...

The two ids called refer to button objects defined in the html file. Does it make a difference if I define them there in the html or if I define them with js syntax (as in `createElement`

Edit to show the html that this code references to:

```
<input type="button" class="css_button" value="Convert to DJ Ticker" id="conv" >
<input type="button" class="css_button" value="Go to website" id="gotof" >
```

As I understand, the buttons have an id, so they should be captured by the getElementById, in order to give them a function.

thanks!

Comment: Quite puzzling. If the buttons are indeed static in the HTML you're loading, this should catch them.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Use console.log to verify that it is cf and gf that are null, and (2) replace the outer addEventListener with window.onload = function () { ... }; . As Chrome App resources are local, onload is plenty fast enough, and it ensures that everything is loaded. If the app works with onload, then you can investigate further why DomContentLoaded isn't working. Also, it would help if you would post the HTML, as maybe there's something there that we could help you spot.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried window.onload and it still gives me the same error. Somehow the value of cf and gf are null, but they should give the value of the buttons (I edited my question with the html for them), and once the value of the buttons has been acquired, it should link the functions specified.

Comment: Still would be helpful to post the ENTIRE HTML and js files. I assume you can reduce the js file to a very small one that also has the problem. That way, if anyone were so inclined, this would allow one to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you include the script at the end of the DOM (after the buttons are listed)